# "The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types."

Tags: typescript

In angular 8 I am getting:

```
ERROR in src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts(73,17): error TS2696: The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
      Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type '{ x: string; xy: string; xz: string; xc: string; xv: string; xb: string; }': x, xy, xz, xc, and 2 more.
```

Normally this would be quite self explanatory, even to a TS noob like me, however, in my code (in my Angular component) I have:

```
dashContent = {
    x: '',
    xy: '',
    xz: '',
    xc: '',
    xv: '',
    xb: ''
}
dashboard = () => {
    this._dashboardService.dashboard().subscribe((success) => {
            this.dashContent = success;
        }, (error) => {
        }
    )
}
```

And the return of `success` is the exact same object but with filled in properties.

Now, I want to actually use this coding since it provides the object with default values but how do I tell TS that this object is correct (I don't want to just slap an `any` type in there)?

**Edit**

The service:

```
@Injectable()
export class DashboardService {
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) {
  }

  dashboard() {
    let admin;
    if (localStorage.getItem('role') == 'company') {
      admin = '/company/getDashboard';
    }
    if (localStorage.getItem('role') == 'admin') {
      admin = '/admin/getDashboard';
    }
    return this.http.get(`${environment.origin}${admin}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you specify that `DashboardService.prototype.dashboard` returns an `Observable<Object>`? If so, you are in error. Please add the definition of the relevant portion of `DashboardService` to the question

Comment: @AluanHaddad No, so it all returns well, with `success` being the json decoded response form the server, I have since figured out it actually means it cannot associate `success` with `dashContent` very well, if I use `any` on that it resolves

Comment: @AluanHaddad the type of value that is presented as `success` from Angular is the generic `T` type

Comment: But, as you say, you should avoid `any` and I'm confident you don't need to resort to it here. Add the code

Comment: @AluanHaddad so how can I say that success = dashcontent without the error?

Comment: It's trivial to do that, but a coherent answer would be much more straightforward if you supplied the method in the service

Comment: @AluanHaddad added the service, it's not my code BTW so it might look really silly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK so firstly, the TypeScript compiler is correct, this is an error and it is meant to be.

Secondly, you are probably wondering where the type `Object` error even came from since you have not used it yourself. What's happened is that `HttpClient.prototype.get` is overloaded with several signatures overload that your call selects defaults to returning `Observable<Object>`. (This is not a great decision on the part of Angular). You can find the overload set at [angular.io](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#description)

There is another overload however, taking a type parameter, that allows the to be resolved without resorting to the use of `any` and compromising the clarity of your code.

I recommend the following:

**dash-content.ts**

```
 export default interface DashContent {
    x: string;
    xy: string;
    xz: string;
    xc: string;
    xv: string;
    xb: string;
}
```

**dashboard.service.**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

import DashContent from './dash-content';

@Injectable()
export class DashboardService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  dashboard() {
    const role = JSON.parse(localStorage.role);
    const url = `${environment.origin}/${role}/getDashboard`;
       
    return this.http.get<DashContent>(url);
  }
}
```

**dashboard.component.ts**

```
import DashContent from './dash-content';

export class DashboardComponent {
  dashContent: DashContent = {
    x: '',
    xy: '',
    xz: '',
    xc: '',
    xv: '',
    xb: ''
  }
  dashboard = () => {
    this._dashboardService.dashboard().subscribe(success => {
      this.dashContent = success;
    }, error => {});
  }
}
```

Note that the original version of the `HttpClient.Protototype.get` call selected this overload:

```
get(url: string, options?: { headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }): Observable<Object>
```

while the revised version selected this overload:

```
get<T>(url: string, options?: { headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }): Observable<T>
```

Comment: Ah yeah, use interfaces to provide definition, sounds sensible

Comment: That's right. By specifying `DashContent` as the type argument for the type parameter `T`, you influence overload selection. Not that this won't affect the actual behavior at runtime whatsoever.